# Backbone.js Collection fetch error

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, backbone.js-collections

I am building my first Backbone app with similar structure to this [Todo MVC example](https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/dependency-examples/backbone_require) with Require.js and also using Backbone LocalStorage. Problem is when I run `TweetsCollection.fetch()` in HomeView, firebug gives me error: `TypeError: options is undefined` `var method = options.update ? 'update' : 'reset';`

**TweetsCollection:**

```
    define([
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'backboneLocalStorage',
    'models/TweetModel'
], function(_, Backbone, Store, TweetModel) {

'use strict';

    var TweetsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

        model: TweetModel,

        localStorage: new Store('tweets-storage'),

        initialize: function() {
            console.log('Collection init...');
        }

    });

    return new TweetsCollection();

});
```

**HomeView init:**

```
initialize: function() {
            this.listenTo(TweetsCollection, 'add', this.addOne);
            this.listenTo(TweetsCollection, 'reset', this.addAll);
            this.listenTo(TweetsCollection, 'all', this.render);

            TweetsCollection.fetch(); // <- Error here
        },
```

I try to follow the example above, but I'm really lost with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line of code where the error occurs is in Backbone's `success` callback that gets executed by `Backbone.sync`. Here's what that method looks like in Backbone `0.9.10`:

```
  options.success = function(collection, resp, options) {
    var method = options.update ? 'update' : 'reset';
    collection[method](resp, options);
    if (success) success(collection, resp, options);
  };
```

Prior to version `0.9.10`, Backbone callback signature was:

```
options.success = function(resp, status, xhr) { ...
```

The `Backbone.localStorage` plugin, which you are evidently using, [executes the callback method as follows (line 146)](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage/blob/master/backbone.localStorage.js):

```
  if (options && options.success)
    options.success(resp);
```

As you can see, it doesn't pass the arguments in correct order, and is missing the `options` argument altogether, which is where you are seeing the error.

So it would seem that the Backbone.localStorage plugin is currently incompatible with the newest Backbone version.

**Edit:** I went to report this issue to the author of the localStorage plugin, but looks like there is already a [GitHub issue and pull request](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage/pull/63) to fix this. It's not merged yet, so in the meantime you can use [phoey's fork](https://github.com/phoey/Backbone.localStorage) or downgrade to Backbone 0.9.9

Comment: Thanks! Downgraded to 0.9.9